# How can I open chrome bookmark manager programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarks

I want to be able to open the bookmarks manager in Chrome from an html anchor tag:

`<a href="chrome://bookmarks/">Chrome Bookmarks</a>`

or programmatically using JavaScript:

`window.open("chrome://bookmarks/")`

Both methods log an error to the console

`Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://bookmarks/`

I understand the security reasons for not allowing webpages to open local files, and that the bookmarks are stored locally, however, it seems to me that there would be an exception for something like bookmarks, or anything at `chrome://` like `chrome://history/` which has the same result.

I've read a bit about a flag that can be set when launching chrome that allows local files to be accessed `--allow-file-access-from-files`.  You can pass an argument after the flag as well specifying a specific file, but you can't expect users to launch chrome this way every time. I can't find any docs on the flag and how exactly it works.

Also, I know there are keyboard shortcuts to open the bookmarks manager and the link to open it in chrome's vertical ellipsis menu. I'm asking to know if it's possible to open chrome bookmarks manager programmatically.

EDIT: I learned that if you are in the context of a chrome browser extension, you can use

`chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'chrome://bookmarks/' });`

Comment: Sounds like  [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You already got an indication if it's possible to access bookmarks - it isn't. It would be a horrendous privacy risk to allow that. There is no reason to allow it.

Comment: Might be able on your very own environment running local software with sufficient rights to remote control your browser like this. But never ever this should be possible from one random weg page.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for linking the XY problem. Good to know. I'll be going through the rest of the "Asking Questions" section of the FAQ linked there.

Comment: @iquellis that makes sense. Not allowed for security.